# animation-nodes interfering with cycles rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation-nodes

I recently installed animation nodes, a painful process after dealing with duplicate files and whatnot. I ended up reinstalling a fresh copy of Blender 2.79 for windows off of blender.org. So I started using it, and it worked fine, in fact, everything was great until I tried to render one frame to see the outcome. 
It showed 
nothing but a checkered rectangle (as if it was still rendering). **However, the top bar stated that it had complete its rendering process.** Viewing it in rendered view works, I checked the console, nothing out of the ordinary, and switched up my rendering devices. Even opened some old projects with the same program build and rendered fine. So I have a feeling that animation nodes interfered with the rendering, but it just doesn't seem right. Any suggestions?

Here is my project, though the music files will be missing...

[image]

Comment: Can you provide blend file? A screenshot for what your scene is and what your node tree does would be helpful in identifying the problem.

Comment: Just click the link and you can download my project. note that the audio files will be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a AN problem. You render from sequencer. You have some strips in VSE, so blender not renders scene, but gets images from VSE.

In render settings you can unclick **Post Processing** -> **Sequencer** to prevent Blender from rendering from VSE.

[image: Unclick this value]

Also you can just ungroup this little guy:

[image]

Blender thinks that it can be an image.