# Blender (2.91) crashes immediately when I press render because of animation nodes addon

Tags: animation-nodes

I am animating a simple scene in blender 2.91 using the animation nodes addon, and everything was going great up until I hit render and then blender suddenly decided to stop working, so now I can't render my final scene and I need some help.   I've tried simplifying my scene as much as possible and still nothing changes.  Also, I know it is the animation nodes addon because when I uninstalled it from my scene everything rendered fine.

Any information about this is very much appreciated.  Thanks!

here is the link to my file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cz_DH9MCKDe_ABp8Q1vzkr0jZ0_CbXEW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100127/animation-nodes-interfering-with-cycles-rendering?rq=1 Possibly related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the add-on is not compatible with blender 2.91. You will have to use a version that is compatible with the version, like 2.83. That is most probably the reason why it isn't rendering. It could also be that the animation nodes are so heavy that they ate up all the Ram at that instance. Try to look for an alternative. Do try the first solution, if it still doesn't work, then try for an alternative add-on.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and let you know if it works : )

Comment: I re-installed 2.83 and now it renders just fine.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: My pleasure. I am just happy that your project works now and you can render it : ) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think, it is a problem of AN.

I checked your file and if you delete this:

[image]

it works.

I did exchange your "scale" to just a new added plane -> i could render it.

So...how did you create your "scale"? Is it a linked object? I am pretty sure this object is making the trouble.

Comment: The scale is just a plane that I edited into an oval shape in edit mode, then gave it a solidify modifier and 1 level of sub-surf.  Sorry if I should know this but I don't exactly know what you mean by "linked object"  could you explain further?  That would be great : )

Comment: @Chris, I have seen your answer and I agree it is much more reasonable, but deleting these things and changing the stuff can cause a lot more issues in the future and there will be a compromise on quality. It is rather better to use an alternative addon rather than having to compromise on quality and face more issues. I still agree with your answer though. Please do remember not to ask for clarification in the answer.

Comment: @ETHAN DAY I would give you a small tip that would save you trouble. Instead of using a plane, you can use a cylinder, scale it down on the Z-axis to the height you want, and scale it on the X or Y axis. You would get a similar shape much faster.